# Copy mySql database table to another database table having different table structure

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I have two mySql database db1 and db2. I need to copy the data from db1 to db2. Both the databases are under the same user. The table structure is different in both the database.

The columns structure are not the same in the tables.

Example

db1.Table1

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |  SessionID  |  Product1_Qty  |  Product2_qty |
-------------------------------------------------------  
|  1   |  12345      |       2        |       1       |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

db2.Table1 (Desired Output)

```
--------------------------------------------
|  id  |  SessionID  |  Product     |  Qty |
-------------------------------------------- 
|  1   |  12345      |  Product_1   |   2  |
--------------------------------------------
|  2   |  12345      |  Product_2   |   1  |
--------------------------------------------
```

**Edit:** For every sessionID (1 row) in db1.Table1 there should be 2 same sessionID (2 rows) in db2.Table1

I need the SQL script to copy data from db1.Table1 to db2.Table1.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below SQL to do this

```
MySQL> insert into db2.Table1 select * from db1.Table1;
```

Comment: The columns in db1.Table1 is different than db2.Table1

Comment: Yes you already mentioned that. Give this query a try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * into databaseName.dbo.table1name from databaseName.dbo.table2name
```

Can you comment is this worked or not

Answer (score 0):

In case you have different number of columns you can use below query.

```
INSERT INTO db1.table1 (`column1`, `column2`)  (SELECT `column3`, `column3` FROM db2.table2)
```